# Install4j sometimes blocks on upgrade in the uninstall section

Tags: install4j

I’m experiencing a strange issue, the installer uses custom resources (some cmd scripts, a java jar file and zips) which are copied at startup in their specific folders. All these custom resources are used before install files action and they check for processes and run a custom java spring boot application.

The installer either blocks the ui in uninstalling previous version but if I cancel the process the files of the previous version were actually removed  the only problem is that it doesn’t proceed further to install the next version, or if the previous version is further away (was generated a longer time before) from the current it crashes without any dump or with some versions the installer successfully uninstalls the previous version and continues the new installation completing the entire flow.

Any idea what I’m missing or how to find what is causing the different behaviours between the versions the installer tries to uninstall?

I’ve added a check for running processes action which is set to actively terminate before uninstalling the previous version action but it didn’t change the behaviour.

When the actions from the uninstall section are moved elsewhere they complete successfully and uninstall all files action remains the last one hanging in the log.

If the uninstaller is run separately and not during an upgrade with the installer it completes successfully.

Comment: This is not a clear enough question for stackoverflow. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com. Please include the .install4j project file. Also ` it crashes without any dump ` -> There will be an installation log in the %TEMP% directory (assuming you run on Windows), please include that file. You can sort by modification time in that folder and find the newest one whose name starts with "i4j".